# Best Practise for passing Exception Messages to Error Page ASP.NET without Session

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, azure, query-string

In my ASP.NET application I am writing an common error page where i would like to display the following:

1. Exception stack trace (for admins).
2. Error message (for all).
3. An event ID.

Approach followed:

1. Defined a custom class as shown below and used Session to save the object in Global.asax
2. Retrived that object in Error page and displayed the error.

   ```
   public class CustomErrorInfo
   {
       public string EventId { get; set; }
       public string ExceptionTrace { get; set; }
       public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
       public string ContextInfo { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return (EventId + "\n" + ExceptionTrace + "\n" + ErrorMessage + "\n" + ContextInfo + "\n");
       }
   }
   ```

Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customErrorMessage = new  CustomErrorInfo();
    customErrorMessage.EventId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    customErrorMessage.ExceptionTrace = exception.ToString().Replace("\n","");

    customErrorMessage.ContextInfo = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();

    customErrorMessage.ErrorMessage = "An unhandled error.";

    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?MsgId=" + customErrorMessage.EventId + "&Msg=" + customErrorMessage.ErrorMessage +
        "&MsgTrace=" + customErrorMessage.ExceptionTrace + "&MsgContext=" + customErrorMessage.ContextInfo);

    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

}
```

But mine is an Azure application hence using Session for holding heaving objects like exception info as in this case is not that recommended.

Hence looking for a approach with which I can pass the custom object in the way that is best suited to the Error page.

I'm looking for some help in using:

- JSON (using Querystring)
- Javascript or
- any other way by which I can pass my custom object to the Error page without using the session context.

Comment: If you're on Azure; do you have any table storage set up?  You could store the details in there and pass a key to the error page

Comment: Yes I do have Tim, but i am suspecting if the value sstored in the table storage whether it can be retirved instantenously?

Comment: THat is on raise of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Server.Transfer to take you to the error page instead. That allows you to maintain page state in memory ([using the HttpContext.Items collection](http://odetocode.com/Articles/111.aspx)). Though you'd need to disable output caching in some situations. The [HttpContext.AllErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.allerrors.aspx) list already contains any exceptions that were thrown during the request.

Storing error details in Azure Tables would be a better solution, as you'd be able to query the error details and set up events based on new messages arriving in the tables. Possible issue here would be if Azure Table storage were the cause of the exception in the first place.

The best solution would be to gather your events using [Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433048.aspx). These can be configured to automatically be transferred to storage on regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

What about using ELMAH & Windows Azure Table Storage, check out Wades blog on it, 'Using ELMAH in Windows Azure with Table Storage': http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-with-table-storage/